# 2D vector check the magnitude

Tags: javascript, vector

I am creating a vector object which as the following function:

```
Vector.prototype.limitTo = function (pScalar) {

    this.normalise();
    this.multiply(pScalar);
    if (this.magnitude() > pScalar) {
        this.magnitude = 30;
    }
    return new Vector(this.getX(), this.getY(), this.getZ());

};
```

In this I am trying to make it comply with the this spec:

"your Vector object should have a ‘limitTo’ function that takes a single scalar number as its parameter. The function should return a newly constructed Vector object that has the same direction as the ‘this’ Vector, but if its magnitude exceeds the given parameter value then it is reduced in size to equal the maximum value. The direction of the Vector should be unaffected, only the magnitude may be altered. If the magnitude of the Vector does not exceed the maximum value, then it should not be altered."

And a jasmine test of:

```
describe("Limit To", function () {
    var limitedVector, magnitude;

    it("Magnitude not exceeding limit", function () {
        limitedVector = vector.limitTo(60);
        magnitude = limitedVector.magnitude();
        expect(magnitude).toEqual(50);
    });

    it("Magnitude exceeding limit", function () {
        limitedVector = vector.limitTo(30);
        magnitude = limitedVector.magnitude();
        expect(magnitude).toEqual(30);
    });
});
```

I have the magnitude not exceeding limit but, am having trouble getting the exceeding limit test.

Comment: Posting these tests is basically useless because we can't see what `vector` is.

Comment: "am having trouble" ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't include your methods, but assigning a number to a method property seems wrong. Most probably you want

```
Vector.prototype.limitTo = function (pScalar) {
  return this.normalise().multiply(Math.min(his.magnitude(), pScalar));
};
```

If `this.normalise()` is in-place, copy your vector first.